# VHDL Syntax Error 10500

Tags: syntax, compiler-errors, vhdl

I am newer to this and this is homework but I am trying to understand this really inconsistent error.  I have 2 errors; one at line 11 and one at line 17, they are both syntax errors

`); -- line 11`

`BEGIN --line 17`

Whole code

```
Library ieee;
Use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
entity addsub4 is

port(
a: in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
b: in std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
e: in std_logic;
carry: out std_logic;
over: out std_logic;
sout: out std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
);
end addsub4;

architecture addsub4 of addsub4 is
signal c: std_logic_vector (4 downto 0);
signal bx: std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
BEGIN
bx <= b xor e&e&e&e;
c(0) <= e;
s <= a xor bx xor c(3 downto 0);
c (4 downto 1) <= (a and bx) or (c(3 downto 0) and (a xor bx));
carry <= c(4);
over <= c(3) xor c(4);
end addsub4;
```

Comment: Please add the errors you are getting

Comment: There are tools that give a bit more info - ghdl -a addsub4.vhdl: "addsub4.vhdl:11:40: extra ';' at end of interface list", and those that tell you why - nvc -a addsub4.vhdl "** Error: unexpected ) while parsing interface declaration, expecting one of constant, signal, variable, file or identifier File addsub4.vhdl, Line 12" (while showing the character and line). The syntax rule in VHDL allows parsing with with a look ahead of one. I thought Altera's 10500 gave you a list of what it was expecting, sort of like nvc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first error; in a PORT declaration, semicolon is a separator, not a terminator. In other words, the last declaration;

```
sout: out std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
```

should just be

```
sout: out std_logic_vector (3 downto 0)
```

...since there's no further declaration to separate.